# Modal image in wp plugin

Tags: html, jquery, css, wordpress

I'm using the plugin "ninja tables pro" to display a long table.
As i use the google sheets importation functionality, i can't use the "lightbox" option.
So i try to create a popup with jquery.

The difficulty is to take the current cliked image to display her without have the prévious one

here is my code :

```js
  
 var btnClose = document.getElementById('btnClose');
btnClose.addEventListener('click',closeModal);
function closeModal() {
overlay.style.display='none';
}
  $(document).ready(function() {
  $('.img').each(function() {
      var currentImage = $(this);
      
      $(this).on("click", function(){
          $(".popup").append("<img class='img' src='" + currentImage.attr("src") + "' alt='' width='400' height='400'>");
          $("#popup").remove("<img class='img' src='" + currentImage.attr("src") + "' alt='' width='400' height='400'>");
            $("#overlay").css("display", "block");
      });
      
     
  });
  
});
```

```css
.overlay {
position: fixed;
left: 0px;
top:0px;
background-color: rgba(0,0 ,0 , 0.5);
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
z-index:36;
display:none;
padding: 500px;
}

.popup{
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
margin-top: -240px !important;
width : 70%;
background-color: rgb(243, 243, 243);
padding: 1em;
box-shadow: 0 15px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
border-radius: 5px;
}

.btnClose {
float: right;
font-size:16pt;
cursor: pointer;
color: rgb(26, 26, 26);
}
```

```html
<img class="img" src="{{row.photoduproduit}}" alt="" width="150" height="150" class="aligncenter size-full wp-image-5505"/>
<div id="overlay" class="overlay">
<div id="popup" class="popup">
<span id="btnClose" class="btnClose">&times;</span>
```

(the img with the "{{rowphotoduproduit}}" is to have the src of the pic in the table)

The problem here is that all time i click on a pic, it show it but with the previous one.

Do you have a idea ?

Thanks you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just use [`empty`](https://api.jquery.com/empty/) method from jquery  to 'empty' the popup before appending the image.

Other Changes made :

- add closing `</div>` tag to `div overlay` and `div popup`
- remove duplicate class attribute on  `img`
- changed `overlay` in `closeModal` to `$('.overlay')`
- changed the use of `style.display` to jquery `hide/show` methods
- made use of [`template strings`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) instead of concatenation for new
  image element

**UPDATE :** Added a solution with [`clone`](https://api.jquery.com/clone/) and commented out the first solution

```js
var btnClose = document.getElementById('btnClose');
btnClose.addEventListener('click', closeModal);

function closeModal() {
  $("#overlay").hide();
}
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('.img').each(function() {
    const currentImage = $(this);
    currentImage.on("click", function() {
      $('.popup').empty();
      // creating a new image with same src
      // const imageToAdd = `<img class='img' src=${currentImage.attr('src')} alt='' width='400' height='400' />`
      // $('.popup').append(imageToAdd)
      
      // clone image and change width/height
      const clonedImage = $( currentImage ).clone().appendTo( ".popup" );
      clonedImage.css({
         'width' : '400px',
          'height' : '400px'
      });
      $("#overlay").show();
    });


  });
});
```

```css
.overlay {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 36;
  display: none;
  padding: 500px;
}

.popup {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
 
  width: 70%;
  background-color: rgb(243, 243, 243);
  padding: 1em;
  box-shadow: 0 15px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.btnClose {

  font-size: 16pt;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: rgb(26, 26, 26);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img class="img" src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" alt="" width="150" height="150" />
<img class="img" src="https://via.placeholder.com/350" alt="" width="150" height="150" />
<div class="overlay">

</div>
<div id="popup" class="popup"></div>
<span id="btnClose" class="btnClose">&times;</span>
```

Comment: @JulienCanet glad i could help. I've also updated the answer with a solution using clone which i think is better than creating a new element.

Comment: oh yes ! i'll update on my website, it will be better, thank you so much!